# While loop won't stop looping

Tags: python, loops

I'm kind of new to python or coding in general and I have run into a problem in my while-loop. I want to point out that the while-loop only works when the variable "loop" = True

```
loop = True #Makes the asking sequence work


def loop_again(): #Makes the program ask if you want to continue
    loop_again = str(input("Do you want to do this again? Yes or No: "))
    if loop_again == "Yes":
        loop = True
    elif loop_again == "No":
        loop = False
    else:
        print("Please answer yes or no: ")
        loop_again
```

When I write "No" when the program asks me if I want to do this again, it still loops the sequence, even though the variable "loop" is supposed to be false when i type "No" which is supposed to stop the loop.

Full code (while loop at the bottom of the code):

```
#Solving for the area in a shape automatically

import math

loop = True #Makes the asking sequence work


def loop_again(): #Makes the program ask if you want to continue
    loop_again = str(input("Do you want to do this again? Yes or No: "))
    if loop_again == "Yes":
        loop = True
    elif loop_again == "No":
        loop = False
    else:
        print("Please answer yes or no: ")
        loop_again



def sqr_area(): #Asking sequence for the area of the square
    if choose == "Square":
        a = float(input("Input the length of the side here: "))
        print(a ** 2)
        loop_again()

def rec_area(): #Asking sequence for the area of the rectangle
    if choose == "Rectangle":
        a = float(input("Input the length of the long sides here: "))
        b = float(input("Input the length of the short sides here: "))
        print(a * b)
        loop_again()

def tri_area(): #Asking sequence for the area of the triangle
    a = float(input("Input the length of the side: "))
    b = float(input("Input the length of the height: "))
    print((a * b) / 2)
    loop_again()

def cir_area(): #Asking sequence for the area of the circle
    r = float(input("Length of the radius: "))
    print((r ** 2) * math.pi)
    loop_again()

while loop == True: #While loop, asking sequence
    choose = str(input("Input what shape that you want to figure out the area of here: "))
    if choose == "Square":
        sqr_area()
    elif choose == "Rectangle":
        rec_area()
    elif choose == "Triangle":
        tri_area()
    elif choose == "Circle":
        cir_area()
    else:
        print("Invalid shape, Input one of these shapes: Square, Rectangle, Triangle, Circle")
        choose
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `else: ... choose` - is that a typo? `choose` is a string.

Comment: Related: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4518341)

Comment: The question to loop again should be in the `while` loop itself, not embedded in each of the `*_area` functions. `loop_again` should *also* use a `while` loop, rather than using unbounded recursion.

Comment: Forgot to mention, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. For questions asking for debugging help, reducing your code into a [mre] is super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use recursion when you should be using a loop, and `loop_again` should *return* a value instead of setting `loop` globally.

```
import math


# Returns true once the input is Yes or false once the input is No
def loop_again():
    while True:
        response = str(input("Do you want to do this again? Yes or No: "))
        if response == "Yes":
            return True
        elif response == "No":
            return False
        else:
            print("Please answer yes or no: ")
```

`loop_again` should be called *after* the relevant `*_area` function has returned, not inside each function. The functions don't need to know or care
about the value of `choose`; they are only called when they are intended to be called.

```
# Print the area of a square
def sqr_area():
    a = float(input("Input the length of the side here: "))
    print(a ** 2)


# Print the area of a rectangle
def rec_area():
    a = float(input("Input the length of the long sides here: "))
    b = float(input("Input the length of the short sides here: "))
    print(a * b)


# Print the area of a triangle
def tri_area():
    a = float(input("Input the length of the side: "))
    b = float(input("Input the length of the height: "))
    print((a * b) / 2)


# Print the area of a circle
def cir_area():
    r = float(input("Length of the radius: "))
    print((r ** 2) * math.pi)
```

The final loop can run indefinitely, until `loop_again` returns `True`.

```
# Loop until the user chooses to not run again
while True:
    choose = input("Input what shape that you want to figure out the area of here: ")
    if choose == "Square":
        sqr_area()
    elif choose == "Rectangle":
        rec_area()
    elif choose == "Triangle":
        tri_area()
    elif choose == "Circle":
        cir_area()
    else:
        print("Invalid shape, Input one of these shapes: Square, Rectangle, Triangle, Circle")
        continue

    if loop_again():
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `loop_again()` function you have to add this at the beginning:

```
global loop
```

Otherwise, the variable is considered *local* and won't have any effect on the *other* `loop` variable that's in the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

It's a context variable problem. The `loop` variable you have in `loop_again()` and the one inside the while loop are different ones. 
Every variable inside a function, in python, is local variable, unless its an argument, or if you use `global variable` in the main and in inside the functions.

So make it global or pass and return it inside the functions

```
#Solving for the area in a shape automatically

import math
global loop 
loop = True #Makes the asking sequence work


def loop_again(): #Makes the program ask if you want to continue
    global loop 
    loop_again = str(input("Do you want to do this again? Yes or No: "))
    if loop_again == "Yes":
        loop = True
    elif loop_again == "No":
        loop = False
    else:
        print("Please answer yes or no: ")
        loop_again



def sqr_area(): #Asking sequence for the area of the square
    if choose == "Square":
        a = float(input("Input the length of the side here: "))
        print(a ** 2)
        loop_again()

def rec_area(): #Asking sequence for the area of the rectangle
    if choose == "Rectangle":
        a = float(input("Input the length of the long sides here: "))
        b = float(input("Input the length of the short sides here: "))
        print(a * b)
        loop_again()

def tri_area(): #Asking sequence for the area of the triangle
    a = float(input("Input the length of the side: "))
    b = float(input("Input the length of the height: "))
    print((a * b) / 2)
    loop_again()

def cir_area(): #Asking sequence for the area of the circle
    r = float(input("Length of the radius: "))
    print((r ** 2) * math.pi)
    loop_again()

while loop == True: #While loop, asking sequence
    global loop 
    choose = str(input("Input what shape that you want to figure out the area of here: "))
    if choose == "Square":
        sqr_area()
    elif choose == "Rectangle":
        rec_area()
    elif choose == "Triangle":
        tri_area()
    elif choose == "Circle":
        cir_area()
    else:
        print("Invalid shape, Input one of these shapes: Square, Rectangle, Triangle, Circle")
        choose
```

you need to say in every function that loop is the global one, otherwise python you interpret it as a local variable.

the other way is:

````
import math
loop = True #Makes the asking sequence work


def loop_again(loop ): #Makes the program ask if you want to continue
    loop_again = str(input("Do you want to do this again? Yes or No: "))
    if loop_again == "Yes":
        loop = True
    elif loop_again == "No":
        loop = False
    else:
        print("Please answer yes or no: ")
        loop_again
    return loop



def sqr_area(loop): #Asking sequence for the area of the square
    if choose == "Square":
        a = float(input("Input the length of the side here: "))
        print(a ** 2)
        loop = loop_again()
    return loop

def rec_area(loop): #Asking sequence for the area of the rectangle
    if choose == "Rectangle":
        a = float(input("Input the length of the long sides here: "))
        b = float(input("Input the length of the short sides here: "))
        print(a * b)
        loop = loop_again(loop)
    return loop


def tri_area(loop): #Asking sequence for the area of the triangle
    a = float(input("Input the length of the side: "))
    b = float(input("Input the length of the height: "))
    print((a * b) / 2)
    loop = loop_again()

def cir_area(loop): #Asking sequence for the area of the circle
    r = float(input("Length of the radius: "))
    print((r ** 2) * math.pi)
    loop = loop_again()

while loop == True: #While loop, asking sequence
    choose = str(input("Input what shape that you want to figure out the area of here: "))
    if choose == "Square":
        loop = sqr_area(loop )
    elif choose == "Rectangle":
        loop = rec_area(loop )
    elif choose == "Triangle":
        loop = tri_area(loop )
    elif choose == "Circle":
        loop = cir_area(loop )
    else:
        print("Invalid shape, Input one of these shapes: Square, Rectangle, Triangle, Circle")
        choose```
````